# TSQL CURSOR and SET Based Alternatives

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

I've read in many places that replacing a CURSOR with a set-based alternative improves performance considerably but I've yet to find an example, tutorial, explanation to what a set-based alternative actually is and how a cursor can be converted into one.

Can anyone provide any links to such please?

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to show us a concrete example .... but basically - instead of doing **RBAR** (row-by-agonizing-row) processing, you issue a single T-SQL statement that does e.g. an `UPDATE` on an entire set of rows (instead of iterating over those rows and updating each one individually)

Comment: Also: see [Understanding “Set based” and “Procedural” approaches in SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34142/Understanding-Set-based-and-Procedural-approaches) or [Replacing Cursors with Set-Based SQL Queries – Part 2](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/helpwithsql/2011/07/06/replacing-cursors-with-set_2D00_based-sql-queries-_1320_-part-2/)

Comment: And furthermore: [The Road to Professional Database Development: Set-Based Thinking](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/the-road-to-professional-database-development-set-based-thinking/) and [How Developers Can Avoid Transact-SQL Cursors](http://www.codemag.com/Article/060113)

Comment: Why would anyone want to iterate through a resultset so that you can update one row at a time? That' silly.

Comment: you'd be surprised ....

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I will read through them now.

Comment: The second link is broken.

Comment: Try [Replacing cursors with set-based SQL queries part 2](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/helpwithsql/2011/07/06/replacing-cursors-with-set_2D00_based-sql-queries-\_1320\_-part-2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for the Relational in RDBMS and you ill see MSSQL, Oracle and others are systems optimized to work with sets. Cursors works more like imperative procedural languages like C#.

For a small example try to implement a join! You can mimic a join by using a cursor to do a nested loop.
Silly example for sure but you get the idea. A join ill be faster than that cursor.

Also note performance is not only about the fatest way. It's about using less resources. That resources are: **CPU, Memory, IO, HD, users patience** (time). Cursors can consume all that resources.

Sometimes cursors can be optimzed using FAST FORWARD and others tricks. Eventualy a cursor can be a option and even the best tool for the work (they exists for a motive).

The problem with cursors is they are over used by developers with lack of set based experience. Those guys tries to apply that C-like programing style to the relational world with horrific results.

**Edit**
Here a example borrowed from [SQL Shack](http://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-cursor-performance-problems/)

```
DECLARE @rowguidVar UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  -- prepare unique ID variable to use in the WHERE statement below

DECLARE test_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT rowguid
FROM   AdventureWorks2012.Sales.SalesOrderDetail
WHERE  ModifiedDate BETWEEN '2008-07-15 00:00:00.000' AND '2008-07-31 00:00:00.000'

OPEN test_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM test_cursor INTO @rowguidVar  
--This is the start of the cursor loop.
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
       SELECT *
          FROM            Sales.SalesOrderDetail
          WHERE    rowguid = @rowguidVar
   FETCH NEXT FROM test_cursor INTO @rowguidVar  
END

CLOSE test_cursor  
DEALLOCATE test_cursor
-- Don't forget these statements which flush the cursor from memory
```

Is the same of

```
SELECT  *
FROM    AdventureWorks2012.Sales.SalesOrderDetail
WHERE   ModifiedDate BETWEEN '2008-07-15 00:00:00.000' AND '2008-07-31 00:00:00.000'
```